# Joining two classes based on common id using LINQ LAMBDA

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I want to join to two classes based on a common id which results into 1 row from parent table and two rows from child table, using lambda/linq. I have pasted below, what I have tried so far but what I get is 10 rows each which is incorrect. Any suggestion or amendment to the code is welcome.

Class

```
namespace x
{
    public class IntegrationSearchResult
    {
        public string Dfe { get; set; }
        public SchoolResult SchoolSearchResult { get; set; }
        public List<PupilResult> PupilSearchResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class SchoolResult
    {
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }              
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public int Pupils { get; set; }     
    }

    public class PupilResult
    {
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }     
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

Functions

```
private Func<IEnumerable<IntegrationSearchResult>> _getAllDummySearchResults;
private Func<string, IntegrationSearchResult> _getDfeDummySearchSchool;
```

My Attempt to achieve the result

_

```
getAllDummySearchResults = () => (from dummySupplierId in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)                                                      
    select new IntegrationSearchResult
    {
        Dfe = "School-1-" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000"),

        SchoolSearchResult = new SchoolResult
        {
            SupplierId = dummySupplierId,
            SchoolName = "SchoolName" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000"),         
            CreateDate = new DateTime(),
            Pupils = 123            
        }
        ,
        PupilSearchResult = new List<PupilResult>
        {
            new PupilResult
            {
                SupplierId = dummySupplierId,                    
                FirstName = "FirstName - Pupil-1-" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000"),
                LastName = "LastName - Pupil-1-" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000")
            },
            new PupilResult
            {
                SupplierId = dummySupplierId,
                FirstName = "FirstName - Pupil-2-" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000"),
                LastName = "LastName - Pupil-2-" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000")
            }
        }
    }).ToList();

    _getDfeDummySearchSchool = dfe =>
    {
        var allSchools = _getAllDummySearchResults();
        return allSchools.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Dfe == dfe);
    };
```

Result expected: School SearchResult should display one row and it's corresponding pupils which is two rows having same supplier id.

```
{
  "Dfe": 0,
  "SchoolSearchResult": [
    {
      "SupplierId": 1,
      "SchoolName": "SchoolName000001",
      "CreateDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Pupils": 123
    }],
     "PupilSearchResult": [
    {
      "SupplierId": 1,
      "FirstName": "FirstName - Pupil-1-000001",
      "LastName": "LastName - Pupil-1-000001"
    },
    {
      "SupplierId": 1,
      "FirstName": "FirstName - Pupil-1-000002",
      "LastName": "LastName - Pupil-1-000002"
    }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the definition of you first method to the following

```
getAllDummySearchResults = () => (from dummySupplierId in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)                                                      
    select new IntegrationSearchResult
    {
        Dfe = "School-1-" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000"),

        SchoolSearchResult = new SchoolResult
        {
            SupplierId = dummySupplierId,
            SchoolName = "SchoolName" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000"),         
            CreateDate = new DateTime(),
            Pupils = 123            
        }
        ,
        PupilSearchResult = new List<PupilResult>
        {
            new PupilResult
            {
                SupplierId = dummySupplierId,                    
                FirstName = "FirstName - Pupil-1-" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000"),
                LastName = "LastName - Pupil-1-" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000")
            },
            new PupilResult
            {
                SupplierId = dummySupplierId,
                FirstName = "FirstName - Pupil-2-" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000"),
                LastName = "LastName - Pupil-2-" + dummySupplierId.ToString("000000")
            }
        }
    }).Take(1).ToList();
```

It will only pick two records from the child collection and when you call the second method on equality, it will call the first method fetching two rows from child class.

Comment: you can sort the inner collection before selecting two rows from it

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to restrict the result by 2. All I want that it should return may be 10 rows from parent table (SchoolResult) and matching rows of child table (PupilResult). With this I am still getting 2 rows from parent table and 2 rows from child table having supplier id 1,2 which is wrong. It should return 2 rows with same supplier id. Thanks

Comment: I have changed `Take(2)` to `Take(1)`. It would get you what you want but I have no idea what exactly you are trying to achieve by such query. If you can put your use case people may be in better position to answer your question

Comment: Ok forget about what I have written, just think about the two classes I have at the top, all I want is the result expected which I mentioned in middle of the post. That's what I wanted to achieve. Thanks

Comment: I think my edited answer will give you your desired results

Comment: Thanks, I have found way to my problem. Cheers

Comment: well, in that case you can post answer to your own question and mark it as an answer so others having similar issue can benefit